# Laravel 9 API return error codes instead of error messages on validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-api

I am trying to make Laravel return error CODES instead of messages along with some extra data depending on the validation error.

Quick examples:
If I have a "unique" validation rule I would expect the result for that field to be:

```
<field>: {
    "code": "unique_rule_error",
    "message": "The username has already been taken."
}
```

If I have, let's say a min rule:

```
<field>: {
   "code": "min_rule_error",
   "value": "100",
   "message": "The username must be at least 100 characters."
}
```

In both examples, the "message" field is unnecessary, I am just keeping it there for the time being.

What I have currently working and almost returning the desired results:

> App\Validators\RestValidator (custom validator, extending the base Validator class)

```
class RestValidator extends Validator
{
    public function addFailure($attribute, $rule, $parameters = [])
    {
        if (!$this->messages) {
            $this->passes();
        }

        $attribute = str_replace(
            [$this->dotPlaceholder, '__asterisk__'],
            ['.', '*'],
            $attribute
        );

        if (in_array($rule, $this->excludeRules)) {
            return $this->exclude`enter code here`Attribute($attribute);
        }

        $message = $this->getMessage($attribute, $rule);

        $message = $this->makeReplacements($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters);

        $customMessage = new MessageBag();

        $customMessage->merge(['code' => strtolower($rule . '_rule_error')]);

        if ($rule !== 'Unique') {
            $parts = explode(':', $this->currentRule);

            if (count($parts) >= 2) {
                $boundaries = explode(',', $parts[1]);
                $boundaries_count = count($boundaries);

                if ($boundaries_count == 1) {
                    $customMessage->merge(['value' => $boundaries[0]]);
                }

                if ($boundaries_count > 1) {
                    $customMessage->merge(['lower' => $boundaries[0]]);
                }

                if ($boundaries_count >= 2) {
                    $customMessage->merge(['upper' => $boundaries[1]]);
                }
            }
        }

        $customMessage->merge(['message' => $message]);

        $this->messages->add($attribute, $customMessage);
    }
}
```

> AppServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
    //
    Validator::resolver(function ($trnslator, $data, $rules, $messages) {
        return new RestValidator($trnslator, $data, $rules, $messages);
    });
}
```

This gives me the results I want with all rules I have currently tried, except when I use the Password validation:

> Password::min(8)->mixedCase()->numbers()->symbols()

This causes a rather strange behavior that I can't explain, the result is the following:

```
"password": [
        {
            "code": "confirmed_rule_error",
            "message": "The password confirmation does not match."
        },
        "{\"code\":\"min_rule_error\",\"value\":\"8\",\"message\":\"The password must be at least 8 characters.\"}",
        "The password must contain at least one uppercase and one lowercase letter.",
        "The password must contain at least one symbol."
    ]
```

The complete password validation code is:
'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Password::min(8)->mixedCase()->numbers()->symbols()]

I want to return error codes like "unique_rule_error" because I will be translating the messages in the front-end with Vue and I don't want to keep track of a locale on the API side.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that Laravel handles responses for strings and classed defined rules in different sections of code.

Laravel 9.34.0 has this chunk of code in `Illuminate\Validation\Validator#603-607`.

[image: Illuminate\Validation\Validator#601]

In your code, the "confirmed" rule is defined as `string`, hence in `#603`, the if statement is `false`, and eventually in `#612` the `addFailure` method is called in `RestValidator`.

The next rule would be `Password::...` which is indeed an instance of `RuleContract` thus an early return is executed preventing the `#612` `addFailure` method in `RestValidator` to be executed.

Checking the `validateUsingCustomRule` method in this same `Illuminate\Validation\Validator` class we find that in `#829` an `add` method is called to populate error messages, you may want to add your logic there as well.
[image: Illuminate\Validation\Validator#825]